# Angular custom pipes with async capability

Tags: angular

I am creating my custom pipe, `culture` which performs some async localdb/http request to return data from the server. Let's look at the following:

`{{ 'hello' | culture:'es-mx' }}`

I need this to be `Hola`, but I want this to be rendered `async`. The `PipeTransform` interface provides me with `transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any` interface. How can I implement it `async`? Is this something doable?

The answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548035/how-to-use-custom-pipe-on-async-pipe), for example suggest the `async` pipe, followed by a `filter/sort` to achieve this to be actively listening to an array changes and filter, but that seems performance heavy because there are many pipes in my application.

I would like to implement something like this:

```
 transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {

        operation.subscribe(result => {
            // set the pipe value from here...
        })


 }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48900163/3731501 as a reference

Comment: You can return an observable, so that it would work with the async pipe (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-psni5j?file=app%2Fcustom-text.pipe.ts)). I don't know if there are major drawbacks to that suggestion, except for requiring the pipe to be used with async.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return an Observable or Promise from a Pipe. Angular [recommends](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#caching-http-requests) caching the data retrieved in a pipe when it's performing an expensive operation because of frequent change detection cycles.
This caching example, linked above is a perfect example of what you want to do. It also describes the `pure: false` property of the `@Pipe` decorator you will want to use in this instance (since I'm assuming the URL for the http get request will change as the text to translate changes).